# MethodCallExpression.Method always returns the root base class's MethodInfo

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Here's a simple application that prints the method signature of a `MethodCallExpression`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class A
{
    public virtual void Foo() { }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Foo() { }
}

class C : B
{
    public override void Foo() { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintMethod<A>(a => a.Foo());
        PrintMethod<B>(b => b.Foo());
        PrintMethod<C>(c => c.Foo());

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void PrintMethod<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression)
    {
        var body = (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;

        var method1 = body.Method;
        var method2 = typeof(T).GetMethod(body.Method.Name, body.Method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("body.Method         -> " + method1.DeclaringType.ToString() + " - " + method1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("typeof(T).GetMethod -> " + method2.DeclaringType.ToString() + " - " + method2.ToString());
    }
}
```

I would expect the program to print out:

```
body.Method         -> A - Void Foo()
typeof(T).GetMethod -> A - Void Foo()
body.Method         -> B - Void Foo() *
typeof(T).GetMethod -> B - Void Foo()
body.Method         -> C - Void Foo() *
typeof(T).GetMethod -> C - Void Foo()
```

But it instead prints out:

```
body.Method         -> A - Void Foo()
typeof(T).GetMethod -> A - Void Foo()
body.Method         -> A - Void Foo() *
typeof(T).GetMethod -> B - Void Foo()
body.Method         -> A - Void Foo() *
typeof(T).GetMethod -> C - Void Foo()
```

When getting the `Method` property for the inherited `MethodCallExpression`, it always returns `A`s `MethodInfo` (the root class).

However, in Visual Studio and I "Go To Definition" of each of the `Foo()` calls, I'm taken to each of the overridden methods as expected.

Why does the `MethodCallExpression.Method` behave this way? Is there anything in the spec about this? Why is there a discrepancy between VS and the `Method` property? I've tested with .NET 4.0 and 4.5.

Comment: Good question. This behavior seems intuitively correct if you think about the code that gets generated - in all 3 cases it is a callvirt to `A.Foo`.

Comment: This behavior got a mention over at the C# Language Design repo on GitHub: see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24347#issuecomment-359070141.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have one library:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Foo() { }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Foo() { }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void Foo() { }
}
```

And you have one consumer that does

```
new C().Foo();
```

Now you update the library so that `C` no longer overrides `Foo`:

```
public class C : B
{
}
```

Will the consumer need to be recompiled?

If the consumer calls `C.Foo` virtually, then yes, and the consumer would have to specifically write `((A)new C()).Foo()` to avoid that problem. If the consumer calls `A.Foo` virtually, then no. Since this is the only difference, since the exact same function will be called at runtime, it makes no sense for the consumer to specify that it calls `C.Foo`.

Expression trees record the same method information that a regular function call would record. The C# specification has very little to say about this, it leaves it implementation-defined (yet Microsoft's implementation doesn't appear to define (document) it):

> Conversion of an anonymous function to an expression tree type produces an expression tree (§4.6). More precisely, evaluation of the anonymous function conversion leads to the construction of an object structure that represents the structure of the anonymous function itself. The precise structure of the expression tree, as well as the exact process for creating it, are implementation defined.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense now that you've explained it. However, it's not very obvious. I would have expected VS and the expression tree to behave similarly.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky Agreed that it's not obvious, but I'm glad the VS devs made an exception to make "Go to definition" work more intuitively than this, even if it means it behaves differently from what C# actually does. :)